# Start application in x-server session from external terminal?

Tags: x-server

How can I start an application in a specific x-server session from outside (e.g.) with putty? Until now I have started a vnc server, logged in, opened the shell and started the application there.

How can I do that from outside?

Answer (score 1):

Most simple X11 applications just need you to set the environment variable `DISPLAY`, so just

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

before running the command may be enough.

Comment: No. I get an segmentation fault what means it tries to start from the shell...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want X11 forwarding through PuTTy on a Windows operating system. Please see the answer to the following related question:

https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty