# How (or is it possible) the Linux desktop X-Server from Terminal under an SU otherusername

Tags: login, su, x-server

I have a simple scenario to demonstrate the use-case for this question

1. Login to Linux as *currentuser*
2. start bash terminal
3. xauth list $DISPLAY

   - `mint/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7b00a8e53b8d9e579c2eaf5009561fa4`
4. change user name

   - su -- *otheruser*
5. `xauth add mint/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7b00a8e53b8d9e579c2eaf5009561fa4`
6. xeyes

Anyway that's the plan.  The reality is that I'm getting a time-out error on the `xauth add` command

```
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/currentuser/.Xauthority
```

... because it is looking at *currentuser*.  So I haven't been able achieve the objective, to run `xeyes` using the *otheruser* login.

Is there a way to  actually login as the *otheruser* account?  Or is the notion off-track in the first place?

---

similar/related questions:

- [Start application in x-server session from external terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214382/start-application-in-x-server-session-from-external-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing more reading and testing.  I have a solution, if not a complete explanation.

1. Login to Linux as *`currentuser`*
2. start `bash` terminal
3. xauth list $DISPLAY

   - `mint/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7b00a8e53b8d9e579c2eaf5009561fa4`
4. change user name

   - **`su -`*`otheruser`***
5. **`XAUTHORITY=/home/`*`otheruser`*`/.Xauthority`**
6. `xauth add mint/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7b00a8e53b8d9e579c2eaf5009561fa4`
7. `xeyes`

The two big differences are steps #4 and #5.  Looking at the **`su`** man page reveals:

> If --login is used, the $TERM, $COLORTERM, $**DISPLAY**, 
>      and $**XAUTHORITY** environment variables are copied if 
>      they were set.

I'll be honest I only found (the import of) that piece of information after I got the `xeyes` to work.  So the first thing to be done is to use

- `su`**`-`**`otheruser`

Using the single dash, means the environment is set by scripts, and Not copied from the *currentuser*.  By default the `.Xauthority` file protection is set as owner-only access:

- `-rw------- 1`*`currentuser`* *`currentuser`*`54 Dec 26 23:21`**`.Xauthority**`

So when the `XAUTHORITY` points to the *`currnetuser`*'s file, there is a File Open failure.  Thus the second change:

- **`XAUTHORITY=/home/`*`otheruser`*`/.Xauthority`**

  Recall, this is one of the environment variables *copied* with the **`su`** command.

I suspect that the only the second change is necessary, for my use I wanted a 'good' logon to *otheruser*, as-if he/she logged on to the Desktop or via ssh.

Final point of advantage; since the `DISPLAY` variable is also copied, you don't need to set and export `DISPLAY` which would be needed with a loop-back  using **`ssh`**.

### progressing

Any every time you login with *su*; the first step is to set the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable to point to the local

- **`~/.Xauthority`**

file.

In the end, it was the environment variable: **`XAUTHORITY`** pointing to the `*currentuser*` that made things not work.  Hope the next person find they've saved a heap of time!